# Is there a way to insert a worksheet directly to Libre Office Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

In MS Office Word, I can insert a worksheet directly from the Insert tab. Is it also possible in Libre Office 3 Writer, that is to insert a worksheet within the program, without the need to open a spreadsheet application?

The only method that I know is to launch LibreOffice Calc and select the range of cells, then copy and paste it in LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding a spreadsheet or any other LibreOffice file is easy using OLE Objects.

### Here's How:

- Go to **Insert→Object→OLE Object**.
  [image: Menu]
- You will be presented with this dialogue:
  [image: Dialogue]
- As you can see at this point, you have two options, to create a new file, or to use an existing file.

#### Using a new file:

If you choose to create a new file, simply click okay, and you will be presented with a new, embedded file. (See below).

[image: Embedded file]

You can edit this as you normally would, without having to open an instance of Calc.

#### Using an existing file:

If you choose to use an existing file, click on the "Create from file" radio button. This will present you with some slightly different options:

[image: Dialogue Without File Selected]

- You can search for a file to use by using the "Search" button (it brings up a file dialogue where you can choose a file).

  > [image: Dialogue With File Selected]
- You can use a local copy of the file by leaving the option "Link to file" unchecked.

  - This provides more flexibility, but takes up more space in your file.
- If you choose to link to the file:

  - It saves space
  - If you move the file, the link will be broken, so keep this in mind.
  - For best results, keep the files in the same directory.

Otherwise, everything else is the same as "Using a new file".

### Example with an actual file:

**Editing:**
[image: Editing an embedded file]

**Viewing:**
[image: Viewing]

Comment: But If U choose `Create from file` option, how can I choose just one sheet ?

Comment: @skowron-line I'm not sure.

Comment: @skowron-line: right click the object, choose Edit, navigate to the desired sheet. Helps if you close the sheet if it's open in Calc.

Comment: If you want the table in the Writer document to be updated when you update the separate spreadsheet in Calc, check that "Link to file" box, which uses [DDE](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Embedding_spreadsheets#Dynamic_Data_Exchange_.28DDE.29).

Answer (score 3):

Look at this topic: http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9981

The alternative is to do **Insert/Ole Object**.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for the link. Although the answers on that link works, I am looking for a way to insert a worksheet without the need to open LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: The alternative is to do Insert/Ole Object...

Comment: It worked. Thank you! Can you please edit your answer to add this, so I can accept it.

Comment: Do you mind adding some instructions to this answer?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.